# Изменение цвета иконок при получении из ресурсов

Tags: delphi, icon

Есть проект. Exe приложение или ресурсная DLL. Берем иконку(и). Иконки вытаскиваю так (тоже пока не важно, как пример), с дальнейшим присвоением `Image1.Picture.Icon.Handle := GuGetMainIcon(48);`

```
Function GuGetMainIcon(const size:byte=32):THandle;
begin
  Result:=LoadImage(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE('MAINICON'), IMAGE_ICON, size, size, LR_LOADTRANSPARENT);
end;
```

Вопрос:

Хранить одинаковые иконки в ресурсах, если используются только разные цвета - довольно накладно (размер файла). Нет ли способа, при получении иконки изменить ее цвет (*без потери прозрачности и ico формата*). Т.е. допустим мы в ресурсах вместо 5 цветных иконок храним только одну, например красную (разных размеров).
А при желании получить из нее, скажем зеленую, выполняли бы некую процедуру:

```
Function GuReColorIcon(const size:byte=32;const NewColor:TColor):THandle;
begin
  Result:=GuGetMainIcon(size);

  Result:=?????
end;
```

Это возможно?

Comment: в то время, когда делфи компилирует ехе в несколько мегабайт размером вы решили экономить сотни байт или килобайт на картинке?

Comment: ну это если одна иконка. а когда много уже экономия налицо.

Answer (score 3):

Если базовая иконка двухцветная (прозрачный и заливка), то вполне можно использовать `TFillRGBEffect` из FireMonkey. Или сделать что-то своё на основе его кода.